# Jquery Ajax Post again returning data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have simple radio buttons. I click this button successfully post and i get the returning data(another radio buttons). 
My problem is i need post again my new data, how to do this?

My Simple Code here;

```
$('.test1').change(function(){
    var test_id= $(this).val(); // my radio button id
        $.post( "getnewdata.php", { test_id: test_id})
        .done(function( data ) {
           $('.test2').html(data);
       });
});
```

this code working. 
but my new(return) data this;

```
<div id="myreturningdata" class="test2 custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" id="test2" name="testt" class="selector" value="1">
            <label class="custom-control-label ml-1 text-muted" for="test2">Test DATA</label>
            <input type="radio" id="test2" name="testt" class="selector" value="1">
            <label class="custom-control-label ml-1 text-muted" for="test2">Test DATA 2</label>
        </div>
```

i want post again this radio some page

```
$('#myreturningdata').change(function(){
            // i want do someting...
    });
```

Hi Stackoverflow users. I am new here. I know my english bad but I want fixed this problem. Thank you for all comments!
Have a nice day!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I properly grasped your question, you have to register the change event after changing the HTML:

```
$('.test1').change(function(){
    var test_id= $(this).val(); // my radio button id
        $.post( "getnewdata.php", { test_id: test_id})
        .done(function( data ) {
           $('.test2').html(data);

           // HERE
           $('#myreturningdata').change(function(){
               // i want do someting...
           });

       });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This code work for me :) Thank you so much again   (and sorry my english)